# Unable to upload the image in protractor

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, protractor, ng-file-upload

Facing following error:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, input[type="images"])

Protractor code:

```
it("image upload",function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.sleep(4000);
    element( by.css('[ng-click="imagePost()"]') ).click();
    browser.sleep(3000);
    var ele = element(by.model("files")).click();
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele),8000,'Ele is not presented');

    var fileToUpload = "C:\Users\Shiva\Desktop\mdkg.jpg;"
    console.log(fileToUpload);
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
    console.log(absolutePath);
    $('input[type="images"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
    element(by.buttonText('Post Image')).click();
    browser.sleep(5000);
});
```

HTML code to upload image:

```
    <div ngf-drop ng-model="files" ngf-pattern="image/*" data-ngf-multiple="true" ng-repeat="image in images1" ngf-size>
        <img  src="{{image}}" width = "100%" height = "100%" class="m-l img-responsive img-rounded m-b" alt="post images">
        </img-crop>
        <span ng-show="loading" class="text-center col-xs-12" ></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-actions ">
    <button type="submit " class="btn-link modal-action ">
        <strong><span class="icon icon-user "></span>postImg</strong>
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="fileinput"   ng-model="files" ngf-select accept="image/* " data-ngf-multiple="true" class="btn-link modal-action">Upload Image
```

Here I am uploding image, when I click on upload image it navigates to local system and it should upload the image. And after uploading it should post.

Comment: Where is your `<input type="images" />` ?

Comment: Thanks @vjarysta. input tag not there in my code but when i put input tag in protractor it is running ,and it is showing popup as files not permitted(in my application when user tries to upload other than images popup will come).

Comment: can anyone answer this still struggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my answer using page objects:

```
this.uploadImage = function(){

var path = require('path');
        var remote = require('../../../../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');
        browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());


        var fileToUpload = '../../mdkg.jpg';
        var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

        var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

            // Unhide file input
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px';  arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileElem.getWebElement());

        fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);

            // take a breath 
        browser.sleep(4000);
        element(by.buttonText('Post Image')).click();
        browser.sleep(4000);
    };

post_text.uploadImage();
```